# Cesium: Random silhouette rendering for gltf files

Tags: blender, cesiumjs

I have a problem with my gltf objects in cesium (I used Blender to create them, 2.8).
When I want to add a silhouette to my object, some of them will get the silhouette but not the others. I exported them all the same way.

In the console I can see that my object get a silhouette with a color but my object doesn't render it.

Does anyone had the same issue and figure out how to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely late to the party here; however, if you make sure to export the model with 'Normals' checked in the Geometry section of the GLTF export options window it *should* work as expected.

File->Export->glTF 2.0->Geometry->Normals

I spent half a day messing with this thinking it was a coding problem...

[Normals checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX9RE.png)